# On the Raspberry Pi Pico 2040 Pinout Diagram, why are I2C bus pairs overrepresented across pins?

Tags: i2c, rp2040, raspberry-pi-pico

[image]

Picture source: [Raspberry Pi's official site](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/images/pico-pinout.svg)

RP2040 is a 32-bit dual ARM Cortex-M0+ microcontroller integrated circuit made by Raspberry Pi Ltd. In January 2021, it was released as part of the Raspberry Pi Pico board and is well known in the field of Electrical Engineering.  The Raspberry Pi Foundation created the pinout diagram above and so it is assumed that this diagram is standard/useful for Electrical Engineering, however, I have found that many online resources state which pins correspond to which I2C bus emphatically without seeming to consider that there are multiple possibilities in the diagram (see circled I2C0 in yellow).

The reason I am asking is that I have had a lot of trouble today getting I2C0 to work using pins 11 and 12 (GP8, GP9) using <Wire.h> and the Arduino Framework, with no signals appearing using a logic analyzer.  I just now found a [tutorial video](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/raspberry-pi-pico-rp2040-i2c-example-with-micropython-and-cc/47d0c922b79342779cdbd4b37b7eb7e2) from DigiKey which confidently states that I2C0 is on pins 16 and 17 (I will try this tomorrow).

I hope that someone can clear up my confusion as this sort of pinout diagram seems pretty standard.  It's possible that this issue is due to my dependence on the Arduino framework when using the RP2040 and there could be other issues I am not aware of because I'm so new to this (for example people seeming to be using multiple versions of the Arduino framework to target the RP2040, see: https://github.com/platformio/platform-raspberrypi/pull/36).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is alternative connection options, you can turn on one of that options by setting appropriate "Function select" field in GPIO*x*_CTRL registers for corresponding pins.

From Arduino environment one can use `::setSDA(pin)`, `::setSCL(pin)` functions to do this
(see https://arduino-pico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pins.html).